# Как сохранить изменения страницы на javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Можно ли, к примеру, сделать кнопку, которая будет добавлять в определенное место новый элемент, например div, а потом это изменение внесет в файл, чтобы добавленный div остался на месте после обновления страницы?
Как можно реализовать что-то подобное?

Comment: отправить содержимое страницы на сервер, который перезапишет файл, только не надо так делать..

Comment: Можете сохранить изменения в LocalStorage

Comment: Можно, но не нужно. Вы лучше опишите задачу, какую хотите решить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучшим решением было бы сохранить информацию в базе данных(сделать [POST](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) запрос) при каждом клике и читать информацию при обновлении страницы(сделать [GET](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) запрос) с помощью 
[AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX).

Вы также можете использовать [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Вам нужно сохранить информацию про элементов в localStorage во времья каждого клика и читать информацию при обновлении страницы. Но я считаю этот подход неправильным, потому что при удалении localStorage(например если вы удалите историю с браузера **localStorage** может удалится) вы потеряйте всю информацию.